# Masked Edit Extender not working with Reg Expression Validator

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I have the following control for a masked edit for phone number.  I have tested the regular expression and it appears to be working correctly.  However, when I have attempted to enter a correct phone number, it returns the error message and I am not sure why.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtphone" Width="10em" runat="server" MaxLength="14"  
 ValidationGroup="test"></asp:TextBox> 
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)| (\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}" 
 ControlToValidate="txtphone" ID="RegExpVal_txtPhone" runat="server" 
 CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="Invalid Format (use: (XXX) 
 XXX-XXXX)" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="test"  />
           <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtphone_MaskedEditExtender" 
 runat="server" Mask="(999) 999-9999" TargetControlID="txtphone" 
 ClearMaskOnLostFocus="False" />
```

Any ideas why this this should not work?